# Python Scrapy - IP net Masking

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I tried to scrape example.com, but after crawling 100 pages , the website was blocked.

How can I rectify that?

Whether AWS is helpful to avoid blocking ?

Comment: I have edited my question here , but since I can't able to ask new questions. Kindly update this as early as possible. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

see instructions on [scrapy faq page](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html#bans):

> Avoiding getting banned
>   Some websites implement certain measures to prevent bots from crawling them, with varying degrees of sophistication. Getting around those measures can be difficult and tricky, and may sometimes require special infrastructure. Please consider contacting commercial support if in doubt.
>
> Here are some tips to keep in mind when dealing with these kind of sites:
>
> - rotate your user agent from a pool of well-known ones from browsers (google around to get a list of them)
> - disable cookies (see COOKIES_ENABLED) as some sites may use cookies to spot bot behaviour
> - use download delays (2 or higher). See DOWNLOAD_DELAY setting.
>     if possible, use Google cache to fetch pages, instead of hitting the sites directly
> - use a pool of rotating IPs. For example, the free Tor project or paid services like ProxyMesh
> - use a highly distributed downloader that circumvents bans internally, so you can just focus on parsing clean pages. One example of such downloaders is Crawlera
>
> If you are still unable to prevent your bot getting banned, consider contacting commercial support.